# Using ffmpeg with xvfb renders a cropped version of the screen

Tags: ffmpeg, debian, x11, xvfb

I'm using the following command to render a video of a chrome browser running inside a virtual frame buffer (using `xvfb`):

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -i :5 -s `DISPLAY=:5 xdpyinfo | grep 'dimensions:'|awk '{print $2}'` -r 30 tests.mpg
```

When I omit the `DISPLAY=:5 xdpyinfo | grep 'dimensions:'|awk '{print $2}'`, it will render at about `1024x768`, so I invoked xdpyinfo to get the resolution of the display and tell ffmpeg about it.

But when I use the command, it shows the same cropped area, only **stretched** to fit the resolution I gave ffmpeg.

I would like to be able to record the whole virtual frame buffer **without cropping or stretching**. Is there a way to do so?

I have compiled ffmpeg from source just this morning, running `v2.8.git`

Comment: Complete console output missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arguments that come *after* `-i` control the output, not the input.

To set the source resolution use `-video_size` with the `xdpyinfo` output *before* the `-i`. For the framerate use `-framerate`.

The format for the `x11grab` input is `[hostname]:display_number.screen_number[+x_offset,y_offset]`.

```
ffmpeg -video_size `DISPLAY=:5 xdpyinfo | grep 'dimensions:'|awk '{print $2}'` -framerate 30 -f x11grab -i :5.0+0,0 output.mpg
```

Check the docs and the guide: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop

Comment: This was the answer. Thank you! It was a bit confusing for me.